# For loop to return all data recorded by date

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'll be direct.

User have wallets, on each wallet they can create a transaction, the transaction can be income or expense.

When a user is creating a transaction he also picks a date when that transaction is created, then I have a controller to display all user transactions. And this is the format to display it. Imagine user have the next transactions.

`Income: > Amount: 50, Date: 03/03/2023`

`Income: > Amount: 50, Date: 03/03/2023`

`Expense: > Amount: 50, Date: 03/03/2023`

`Income: > Amount: 100, Date: 03/16/2023`

`Expense: > Amount: 15, Date: 03/16/2023`

And on the page I would like to display:

`Transaction: 03/03/2023/ Balance: 100` Because, that is `income - expense`

`Transaction: 03/16/2023/ Balance: 85` Because, that is `income - expense`

How I tried and what are various outputs based on attempts:

```
@GetMapping("/userTransactions/{user_id}")
public String getUserTransactions(@PathVariable("user_id") long user_id, TransactionGroup transactionGroup, Model model) {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    UserDetailsImpl user = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
    long userId = user.getId();
    model.addAttribute("userId", userId);

    List<Transaction> transactions = transactionRepository.getTransactionsByUserId(user_id);
    List<TransactionGroup> transactionByDate = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Transaction> transOnSingleDate = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean currDates = transactions.stream().findFirst().isPresent();

    if (currDates) {
        LocalDate currDate = transactions.get(0).getDate();

        TransactionGroup transGroup = new TransactionGroup();

        for (Transaction t : transactions) {
            if (!currDate.isEqual(t.getDate())) {
                transGroup.setDate(currDate);
                transGroup.setTransactions(transOnSingleDate);
                transactionByDate.add(transGroup);
                transGroup = new TransactionGroup();
                transOnSingleDate = new ArrayList<>();
            }

            transOnSingleDate.add(t);
            currDate = t.getDate();
        }
        transGroup.setDate(currDate);
        transGroup.setTransactions(transOnSingleDate);
        transactionByDate.add(transGroup);


        for (int i = 0; i < transactionByDate.size(); i++) {
            LocalDate date = transGroup.getDate();
            transactions = transGroup.getTransactions();
            double income = transactions.stream()
                    .filter(trans -> trans.getTransactionType().getDisplayName().equalsIgnoreCase("income"))
                    .mapToDouble(Transaction::getAmount)
                    .sum();
            double expense = transactions.stream()
                    .filter(trans -> trans.getTransactionType().getDisplayName().equalsIgnoreCase("expense"))
                    .mapToDouble(Transaction::getAmount)
                    .sum();
            double left = income - expense;
            System.out.println("date:" + date + ",income:" + income + ",expense:" + expense + ",left:" + left);
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Empty");
    }


    model.addAttribute("transactionGroup", transactionByDate);
    return "transactions";
}
```

And that works fine, all transactions are displayed, but the problem is with looping through transaction dates.

If I loop through `transactions` like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < transactionByDate.size(); i++) {
```

then this is the response:

`date:2023-03-16,income:100.0,expense:15.0,left:85.0`

as you can see, only one date is printed, instead of:

```
date:2023-03-16,income:100.0,expense:15.0,left:85.0
```

```
date:2023-03-03,income:150.0,expense:50.0,left:50.0
```

If I try to loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < transactions.size(); i++) {
```

its same,

If I try to loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < transGroup.getTransactions().size(); i++) {
```

it's also the same.

So my question is, how to loop through this list so actually I can get output like:

```
date:2023-03-16,income:100.0,expense:15.0,left:85.0
```

```
date:2023-03-03,income:150.0,expense:50.0,left:50.0
```

Because I have transactions on those two dates. Or for example if user have transactions on three different days, show him output like:

```
date:2023-03-16,income:100.0,expense:15.0,left:85.0
```

```
date:2023-03-03,income:150.0,expense:50.0,left:50.0
```

```
date:2023-03-19,income:200.0,expense:50.0,left:150.0 > new date
```

`Thymeleaf:`

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/transaction.css}"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9ab80cc16b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Users</title>
</head>
<body>

<header>
    <h1 class="logo">Spender</h1>
    <input type="checkbox" class="nav-toggle" id="nav-toggle">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a th:href="@{/api/test/homePage}">Homepage</a></li>
            <li><a id="wallets" th:href="@{/api/wallet/userWallet/balance/{userId} (userId=${userId})}">Wallets</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript: document.logoutForm.submit()" role="menuitem">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <label for="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle-label">
        <span></span>
    </label>
</header>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="date" th:each="singleGroup : ${transactionGroup}"> <h1 th:text="${singleGroup.date}"></h1>
    <h2 th:text="${balance}"></h2>
    <div class="transaction" th:each="singleTrans : ${singleGroup.transactions}">
<h2>Amount: <span th:text="${singleTrans.amount}"></span></h2><br>
        <h2>Note: <span th:text="${singleTrans.note}"></span></h2><br>
        <h2>Wallet name: <span th:text="${singleTrans .walletName}"></span></h2><br>
        <h2>Expense Category: <span th:text="${singleTrans .expenseCategories}"></span></h2><br>
        <h2>IncomeCategory: <span th:text="${singleTrans .incomeCategories}"></span></h2>
        <a class="card__link" th:href="@{/api/transaction/delete/{id}(id=${singleTrans.id})}"
           th:data-confirm-delete="|Are you sure you want to delete ${singleTrans.walletName} wallet?|"
           onclick="if (!confirm(this.getAttribute('data-confirm-delete'))) return false">Delete</a>
        <a class="card__link" th:href="@{/api/transaction/showFormForUpdate/{id}(id=${singleTrans.id})}">Update</a>
        <hr>
</div>

</div>
<div style="text-align:center"
     th:if="${#lists.isEmpty(transactionGroup)}"><h1>You don't have any transaction</h1>
    <a th:href="@{/api/wallet/userWallet/balance/{userId} (userId=${userId})}">Wallets</a>
</div>


<form name="logoutForm" th:action="@{/api/auth/signout}" method="post" th:hidden="true">
    <input hidden type="submit" value="Sign Out"/>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to print each transaction or just the total income/expense for each day?

Comment: No, I don't need to print every transaction, I just want to print total balance for each date where transactions are created, for example, if on `03/03/2023` user created three transactions and I want to print `income - expense` result. I think I gave a good example at the end of the questions about what expected output is. 

If the user has transactions for 10 different dates, show `income - expense` result for every date

Comment: See the example in question after `.... Imagine user have the next transactions.` and also I provided more examples at the end of the question.